# Only dynamic silverlight code without any server compiling

Tags: silverlight, dynamic-compilation

Is it possible to **only** use a **managed dynamic language** such as javascript in a Silverlight application, with **no server side compilation** before deploying to the client?  I'm looking for 0 server side compilation of any code here - would like the entire application to be 100% compiled/interpreted in the browser. I skimmed through the [DLR specs](http://dlr.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Docs%20and%20specs&referringTitle=Documentation) but I didn't notice such an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the answer is yes. Silverlight is a pure client side technology that runs a cut down, secure CLR in a plug in. The Silverlight API is accessible scripting languages including Javascript, F#, IronPython and IronRuby.

However, it is questionable whether you should progress because there doesn't seem to be any community or support around this. Furthermore, Silverlight is in support mode and you have to consider whether it is worthwhile investing your energy in such a dimly lit corner.

There are a few technology demonstrations by Jimmy Schementi [here](http://jimmy.schementi.com/). Also check out the [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Language_Runtime#References) in DLR Wikipedia entry. The old silverlight forums used to have an entire subforum dedicated to Javascript and Silverlight. This is now gone. Consider that as a warning if you decide to progress in this direction.

A few years back, there was an SDK that included a working IronPython and IronRuby with Silverlight, some demos and build scripts. Look for [Chiron](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/10/10/where-is-chiron-in-silverlight-2-release.aspx), which packages scripts and xaml into a single .xap (zip) file. This is in the DLR. There were some cool examples which demonstrated a python and ruby interpreter running in the client side in a Silverlight plugin.

Alternatively, you can develop most of your application in a typed language and then expose parts of it to javascript via a Javascript bridge. The MSDN has some short write up on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks.  This [IronPython article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163284.aspx) by Jimmy Schementi is a good example of 100% dynamic solution.  You're right, doesn't seem like there's much documentation or support for this sort of thing out there.

Comment: There's also another, very nice [IronPython article](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/silverlight/silverlight_application.shtml) demonstrating fully dynamic silverlight solution with Chiron packaging